# Is there any function that can change the column names dynamically as per filter changes in Tableau CRM

Tags: filter, salesforce, dynamic-columns

Is it possible changing the columns dynamically in Tableau crm lens as per filter changes.?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly your issue is; but you can bind your static toggle to make the changes in columns of a lens.